# Where are my XDF files physically?

Tags: memory-management, revolution-r

In Rstudio, my workspace takes about 1Go (.Rdata file)
My xdf files are in my file system, as they should. 
But my session takes over 20Go of RAM even when I'm not running anything. 
How can I free some space here ? I've tried the `gc()` command.

Comment: [This page from Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#object-size) might be useful. Are you perhaps reading your data into memory first, writing it to an XDF, and then leaving it in memory?

Comment: I am using `RxOdbcData` and `rxImport` directly to an xdf